# getting http 408/409 and 503 in REST API call

Tags: java, http, rest

I am trying to make REST API call to external server from an internal application. I am using HTTP Url connection . I have used system.setproperty( http.proxyhost) to connect . When i run in my local pc i am able to read the response from the external server. But  when i tested the application in test environments i am getting HTTP 503 proxy error and http 408/409 server busy. but when i refresh the browser i am able to see that responses are loaded . what might be the issue? how to use proxy in rest api call

Comment: in short "connectivity or configuration issues" might be the cause. I'm not sure how could anyone answer in more detail with the description you've provided.

Comment: Your question isn't descriptive enough to answer. There are several reasons that these codes could be returned. Post more information about your setup *and* your code, then we my be able to more appropriately answer your question.

Comment: thanks for your responses..its a proxy issue... resolved it..

Comment: HTTP 400 codes are on the client-end, not server-end.